# How to get cluster status from IHS WAS plugin?

Tags: webserver, websphere, monitor

I'm fronting a cluster of WebSphere App Servers with IHS(IBM Http Server) and WAS plugin as load balancer. And now I want to get the **cluster statistics** like request rate for each cluster. I went through a few IBM docs, mainly found something related to status_mod or log analyse, however it looks difficult to get cluster stats out of them. I'm wondering if there are any better ways.

For example, when using Apache + mod_jk + tomcat, I have JK Status Manager showing load balance worker stats nicely. Is there anything alike for IHS + WAS?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with (in plugin config file):

```
<Config ...>
  <Log LogLevel="Stats" Name="/path/to/http_plugin_stats.log" />
  ...
</Config>
```